# ESP8266 Webserver ESP8266WebServer move Handler-Function in separate .h .c file

Tags: esp8266, programming, web-server, code-review

The plan is to create a bigger project and to split the ESP8266 webserver-code over several modules (.h .c files). The main problem is that the ESP8266WebServer **server** is not declared in the index.h and index.c files.

What I've been trying to do:

Content main.c

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "ESP8266WebServer.h"
#include "index.h"

ESP8266WebServer server(80);
const char* ssid =     "test";     
const char* password = "12345678";  

void setup() 
{
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  server.on("/", handleRoot(server));           // <-- use of deleted function 'esp8266webserver::ESP8266WebServerTemplate<WiFiServer>::ESP8266WebServerTemplate(const esp8266webserver::ESP8266WebServerTemplate<WiFiServer>&)'
  server.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  server1.handleClient();
}
```

Content index.h:

```
void handleRoot(ESP8266WebServer server); 

const char htmlIndex[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
)=====";
```

Content index.c:

```
#include "webpages/index.h"

void handleRoot(ESP8266WebServer server) 
{
  Serial.println("GET /");
  server.send(200, "text/html", htmlIndex);
}
```

How can I use the ESP8266WebServer **server** created in the main.c in index.c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the webserver to index.c and include the webserver type:

```
ESP8266WebServer server(80);
```

Add an external reference in index.h and include it:

```
#include "ESP8266WebServer.h"

extern ESP8266WebServer server;
```

Index.h is included by both main.c and index.c so it will know about server being an ESP8266WebServer type, but does not allocate memory for it; that is done in index.c

This is called a forward reference.

Comment: I shifted  
`#include "ESP8266WebServer.h"
extern ESP8266WebServer server;` to main.h and included it in index.c but in the end it is your idea. thx.

Comment: Yes, in principle it does not matter where you place the external variable, as long as it is not in a header file (or at least not one that is included twice). Good luck with your project.